# Why it's happen in php? what is the meaning of the output?

Tags: php, class, assign

```
class foo {
    public $x;
    function __construct() {
        $this->x = 5;
    }
}


$foo1 = $foo2 = new foo;
$f1 = $f2 = 5;

echo "foo1 = ".$foo1->x;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "foo2 = ".$foo2->x;
$foo2->x = 50;

echo PHP_EOL;
echo "foo1 = ".$foo1->x;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "foo2 = ".$foo2->x;
```

[image: screenshot]

Why it's happen in php? what is the meaning of the output?
I have last time asked without code.

Comment: Oh I remember this question, [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6SRM.jpg) actually gave it away; I remember it all too well. That post is either deleted or under another account.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I hope you're rolling well. Thank Jedward it's Friday!!! (Why is being behind on work making me keep coming back to SO `:-(` )

Comment: @Martin Aye, that I am mate. Hope all's well with y'all too. TGIF!

Comment: I wish I could find that GIF of a programmer rolling down a hill; always makes me laugh ( the keyboard is the centre of the "wheel")

Comment: because of this: $foo1 = $foo2 = new foo;

Answer (score 6):

```
$foo1 = $foo2 = new foo;
```

Both variables hold the very same object, so setting `$foo2->x = 50` also sets it for `$foo1` since it's just another name for the same thing.

Comment: This has nothing do with references. It's because objects are not copied when they're assigned, like arrays are.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are assigning $foo1 and $foo2 to the same object. Therefore $foo1->x is the same variable as $foo2->x

What you actually want is creating two different instances of the class foo.

For example:

```
$foo1 = new foo();
$foo2 = new foo();
```

If you need further explaination you can take a look at [the page about objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) in the php documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike arrays, objects in PHP are not copied when they're assigned. So `$foo1` and `$foo2` both refer to the same `foo` object. Any changes made to that object will be visible through either variable.

You can either initialize them with separate objects by using `new foo` twice:

```
$foo1 = new foo;
$foo2 = new foo;
```

or you can use `clone` to copy the object:

```
$foo1 = clone $foo2 = new foo;
```